# OpenMP critical section matrix multiplication

Tags: c, openmp

First of all I know the example is not a noticeable improvement from a single threaded execution. I am learning the basic of OpenMP and I dont know why it doesnt work as I expected.

So, I am parallelizing the traditional matrix multiplication algorithm and finding what loops can be parallelized and which not. The algorithm is:

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        for (k = 0; k < SIZE; k = k + 1)
            C[i][j] = C[i][j] + A[i][k] * B[k][j];
```

I know that putting a parallel for on the k loop can cause unexpected results so I want to use a critical section to fix it like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        #pragma omp parallel for shared(C)
        for (k = 0; k < SIZE; k = k + 1)
        {
            int tmp = A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            #pragma omp critical 
            {
                C[i][j] += tmp;
            }
        }
}
```

But when comparing results with the code below correct gives me 0. D is the matrix without omp.
I know there are better ways to do this with reduction but I am learning about critical sections and want to know why this doesnt work.

```
int correct = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE && correct; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE && correct; j++)
            if (C[i][j] != D[i][j])
                correct = 0;
```

Comment: I know very little of OpenMP but shouldn't the `#pragma omp critical` rather protect the `A[i][k] * B[k][j]` part? Since that's where you'll mess up the parallelization (and cache access). The `C[i][j] += tmp;` part isn't critical and `tmp` should have thread local storage per thread.

Comment: why is AB part critical? only reads are done in those two matrices. in C += tmp there are reads and writes on C and both things should be done without any other thread modifying C.

Comment: Note that an `atomic` clause should be prefered over `critical` in such a case.

Comment: @BrightSoul As long as the sequence is just ever-increasing, it is perfect for parallelization and data cache both. When you start to access items out of sequential order, as with the `A[i][k] * B[k][j]`, you break that. Lets say there's 200 items and thread 1 calculates the first 100 and thread 2 the next 100. Thread 1 would stick to its 100 items except when you do this out of order access, then it would go sticking its nose into the data used by thread 2 and vice versa. Hence the need to make that access thread safe.

Comment: @Lundin I understand that when you are writing and reading on the same array but A and B are read only and tmp is private for each thread.

Comment: @BrightSoul you're right, but even in the serial version the memory access pattern is not optimal. When k varies, `B[k][j]` is not accessed contiguously in memory, hence poorer performances. The problem can be fixed by swapping the loops on `k` and `j`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two fairly basic bugs in my code.

- The tmp var is int when it should be double.
- After changing tmp to double. The comparison between two doubles it is not associative and an epsilon should be taken in consideration when comparing.